# How to know if android phone is inside of a certain building name?

Tags: android

I was wondering was there a way to track if the android device is inside of a building and retreieve what building by using the location manager? without having GPS being turned on.

Comment: @Jonners Sure Thanks! You were a big help, I think i found my answer there! *cheers*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you had a Lat/Lon location, you would then use GeoCoding to get the address from the location, addresses may be shown as 2 or 3 buildings in a single location, my home address is shown as a range of house numbers including my neighbours. Without accurate GPS, you wont have enough accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

Android device can get device location over the WIFI or from GSM antennas too, but this is not very accurate. Location technology that is "coarse" only knows where you are within several hundred meters. I think you can not get right results.

If you want to try it, you need to add `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` permission to the AndroidManifest.xml file.

Comment: It is possible, but like I said, this is not accurate. If GSM signal is low, then results are unpredictable.

Comment: It's not accurate enough to be reliable, imo. Basically you'll be relying on Google's database of wifi locations. Provided the signals in range are in the database, you might get location to something like 82-84 xxx Road for residential areas, possibly to the (large) building accuracy in cities.